# Как изменить прогресс QProgressBar, который находится в QTableWidget в PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qprogressbar, qstyleditemdelegate

Я взяла пример кода из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297186) для того, чтобы добавить `QProgressBar` в `QTableWidget`. Но я не знаю, как мне после создания получить доступ к `QProgressBar`, например для изменения текущего значения. Вот что я пробовала:

```
self.table.item(0, 2).setValue(50)
```

Я думала можно получить `QProgressBar` через `item()`, но этот код выдаёт ошибку `'QTableWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setValue'`. То есть таким образом доступ к `QProgressBar` не получить, я так понимаю из-за того, что используется `setItemDelegateForColumn`. Так вот, как можно изменить значения таких прогресс баров?

**Полный код:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80),
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]


class ProgressDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.minimum = 0
        opt.maximum = 100
        opt.progress = progress
        opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
        opt.textVisible = True
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tw = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        delegate = ProgressDelegate(self.tw)
        self.tw.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)
        self.tw.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
        for r, (_id, _name, _progress) in enumerate(data):
            it_id = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            it_name = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
            it_progress = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            it_progress.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000, _progress)
            self.tw.insertRow(self.tw.rowCount())
            for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_progress)):
                self.tw.setItem(r, c, item)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tw)
        button = QPushButton('Запуск')
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def button_click(self):
        try:
            for val in range(0, 100):
                self.tw.item(0, 2).setValue(val)
        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', str(e), QMessageBox.Ok)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Для примера я хотела попробовать сделать заполнение прогресса от 0 до 100 после нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы не ищем легких путей - только трэш и хардкор? :)
Зачем тут делегаты стесняюсь спросить? Они совсем для других целей нужны. Используйте `setCellWidget`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80),
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tw = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.tw.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
        for r, (_id, _name, _progress) in enumerate(data):
            it_id = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            it_name = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
            self.tw.insertRow(self.tw.rowCount())
            for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name)):
                self.tw.setItem(r, c, item)
            cellProgress = QProgressBar() # Создаете свой виджет для отображения в ячейке
            cellProgress.setValue(int(_id)*10)
            self.tw.setCellWidget(r,2,cellProgress) # и говорите табличке что в ее ячейче будет виджет а не текст

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tw)
        button = QPushButton('Запуск')
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def button_click(self):
        for i in range(self.tw.rowCount()):
            pb = self.tw.cellWidget(i,2) # получаете виджет ячейки
            pb.setValue(pb.value()+10) # делаете все что нужно



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```